# LINQ Query for particular situation

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say that I have following tables:

```
 Student(id(pk), name)
 Class(id(pk), name)
 StudentClass(id(pk), studentId(fk), classId(fk))
```

Imagine as follows:

`Student` table contains:

```
 (1,"John"), (2, "Mike"), (3,"Josh")
```

`Class` table contains:

```
(1,"Geography"), (2, "Math")
```

`StudentClass` table contains:

```
(`1, 1, 1),(2,2,2),(3,3,2)
```

Lets now assume that I have a `StudentClassDTO` class which contains

```
List<string> StudentNames
string ClassName
```

How can I by using using LINQ query get data into `StudentClassDTO`? Any help appreciated.

```
    var data = from sc in context.GetStudentClasses
               join s in context.GetStudents on sc.StudentId equals s.Id
               join c in context.GetClass on sc.ClassId equals c.Id
               select new StudentClassDTO
               {

               }
```

so it gets name and classname 3 seperate ones but I need if their classes are same it should have to combine them where it will be just one classname and 2 different students. So it should be like {john, Geography} and {[Mike, Josh], Math}

**Solution**

```
                   from c in classes
                   join sc in studentClasses on c.Id equals sc.ClassId
                   join s in student on sc.StudentId equals s.StudentId 
                   group s by new {c.Name} into g
                   select new StudentClassDTO
                   {
                       ClassName = g.Key.Name,
                       StudentNames = g.Select(a=>a.Name).ToList()
                   };
```

Comment: Have you tried googling a tutorial? There are many out there which will teach you in great detail how to perform this task. If you suffer problems you can come back and us.

Comment: What specifically are you struggling with here? Mapping the many-to-many relationship on your model? Finding a Select expression to get the results? Can you share the code you've tried and tell in what way it's failing to do what you're asking?

Comment: I actually tried joins but in this case I am only able to get datas to StudentClassDTO like this so it gets  name and classname 3 seperate ones but I need if their classes are same it should have to combine them  where it will be just one classname and 2 differen students

Comment: @Kakos649 the time you took to write this symbolic content, by this time you could have written the real code and sample data.

Comment: so it should be lke {john, Geography} and {[Mike, Josh], Math}

Comment: @TanvirArjel sorry for that, done

Comment: LINQ has a special (non-SQL) operation for this - group join. Use an `into` clause on the Students `join` and then put that in the DTO.

Answer (score 0):

I use code like this all the time to accomplish what you're trying to do (untested and using the C# 7.3 syntax).

```
var xs =
    from s in ctx.students 
        join cs in ctx.student_classes on cs.student_id equals s.student_id 
        join c in ctx.classes on c.class_id equals cs.class_id

    select new 
    {
        s, c
    }

var memo = new Dictionary<int, StudentClassDTO>(); //the key is class_id

foreach(var x in xs)
{
    if(!memo.Contains(x.c.class_id, out var @class))
        memo.Add(x.c.class_id, @class = new StudentClassDTO(x.c.class_name));

    @class.Accept(s.student_name);
}


sealed class StudentClassDTO
{
    readonly List<string> student_names;

    public string ClassName { get; }

    public IEnumerable<string> StudentNames => student_names;       

    public(string class_name)
    {
        ClassName = class_name;
    }

    public void Accept(string name) => student_names.Add(name);     
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am trying to accomplish it without extra functions by just LINQ query

Comment: @Kakos649 -- Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq).

Answer (score 0):

Using the LINQ group join operator, you can get a collection of matching student classes, however your query needs to start from the Class table since you want one `StudentClassDTO` per class. Unfortunately you have to nest the `join` from student classes to students (an EF navigation property may do better) so this may generate multiple queries.

```
var data = from c in context.GetClass
           join sc in context.GetStudentClasses on c.Id equals sc.ClassId into scj
           select new StudentClassDTO {
               ClassName = c.Name,
               StudentNames = (from sc in scj
                               join s in context.GetStudents on sc.StudentId equals s.Id
                               select s.Name).ToList()
           };
```

Comment: @Kakos649 I fixed the query, but it may generate multiple SQL queries to get the answer, I can't test that.

Comment: Already added solution you can check it out but thanks for the comment

Comment: @Kakos649 Depending on SQL engine (and LINQ provider), join may be better than group by. Or worse.